# Como posso pegar todos os dados armazenados em um array

Tags: delphi, firebird

Estou programando um sistema em delphi que devera disparar e-mails automáticos, e para armazenar alguns dos emails que tem em meu banco dados, os coloco em um array da seguinte forma?

```
function TFormMain.getEmail: string;
var
mailBill: array of string;
matriz: array of integer;
i,rec: integer;
begin
 i := 0;
 rec := FDQuerySale.RecordCount;
 SetLength(mailBill, rec);

 SetLength(matriz, Length(matriz) + 1);
 matriz[Length(matriz) - 1] := rec;

 FDQuerySale.Close;
 FDQuerySale.SQL.Clear;
 FDQuerySale.SQL.Add('SELECT id_clients,billed FROM sales  WHERE billed = ''N''  ');
 FDQuerySale.Open();
 while not (FDQuerySale.Eof) do
 begin
   matriz[i] := FDQuerySale.FieldByName('id_clients').AsInteger;
   FDQuerySale.Next;
   inc(i);
 end;
 FDQuerySale.Close;

 FDQueryClient.Close;
 FDQueryClient.SQL.Clear;
 FDQueryClient.SQL.Add('SELECT id_clients, email FROM clients WHERE id_clients = :vId_client');
 FDQueryClient.ParamByName('vId_client').Value := matriz[i];
 FDQueryClient.Open();
 mailBill[i] := FDQueryClientEMAIL.AsString;
 FDQueryClient.Close;
```

Como posso pegar todos esses dados e disparar todos os e-mails ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Aqui Delphi+Firebase Firestone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUzzpoePoIs e sobre o CRUD de Delphi+Firebase https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elDPIndONEQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem um problema de lógica aqui:

```
FDQueryClient.ParamByName('vId_client').Value := matriz[i];
```

matriz[i] possui um resultado apenas, pois, você esta acessando uma posição especifica.

O ideal seria utilizar `WHERE id_clients IN(1, 2, 3, ...)`. Porem vale lembrar que no **firebird** o IN (passando valores) possui uma limitação de 1500 itens.

Você também não precisa requisitar ao banco de dados as vendas e os clientes separadamente.

Podemos melhorar a consulta para algo como:

```
SELECT C.email
FROM sales S
JOIN clientes C on C.id_clients = S.id_clients
WHERE S.billed = ''N''
  AND C.id_clients > 0 -- aqui é para acionar algum indice
```

Agora uma nova estrutura de repetição melhorada:

```
FDQuerySale.First;    
while not FDQuerySale.Eof do
begin
  SetLength(matriz, Succ(Length(matriz)); // dimensiona a matriz conforme necessário
  matriz[High(matriz)] := FDQuerySale.FieldByName('email').AsString
  FDQuerySale.Next;
end;
```

Para disparar todos os email simultaneamente podemos utilizar thread, porém, precisa de muito controle para execuções assim.

Basicamente podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
TParallel.For(0, Pred(Length(matriz)),
  procedure (i: integer)
  begin
    TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure
      begin
        EnviarEmail(matriz[i]);
      end)
  end);
```

Com um pouquinho de analise em cima dessa resposta conseguimos reparar que não precisamos nem mesmo desse array "matriz", poderia ser tudo feito na estrutura de repetição do FDQuerySale.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta realmente, funcionou muito bem!